# Pandas - Get dummies from an iterable of iterables with count of appearances

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm having a `Pandas DataFrame()` and within it, some columns are `Pythons' lists` which contains `strings`.
I'd like to transform those columns into dummies that "binarizes" the strings and count their appearances.

As a simple example we can look at the following

```
import pandas

df = pd.DataFrame({"Hey":[['t1', 't2', 't1', 't3', 't1', 't3'], ['t2', 't2', 't1']]})

df
Out[54]: 
                        Hey
0  [t1, t2, t1, t3, t1, t3]
1              [t2, t2, t1]
```

I've managed to do the following:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Hey']), columns=list(map(lambda x: 'Hey_' + x, mlb.classes_)))
Out[55]: 
   Hey_t1  Hey_t2  Hey_t3
0       1       1       1
1       1       1       0
```

Which doesn't count their appearances, but only yield 1 for occurances and 0 for absence. I'd like the following output:

```
   Hey_t1  Hey_t2  Hey_t3
0       3       1       2
1       1       2       0
```

Which counts their appearances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`CountVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) but necessary join `list`s:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

countvec = CountVectorizer()
counts = countvec.fit_transform(df['Hey'].str.join(' '))
df = pd.DataFrame(counts.toarray(), columns=countvec.get_feature_names())
print (df)
   t1  t2  t3
0   3   1   2
1   1   2   0
```

Another solution:

```
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(df['Hey'].values.tolist())
        .stack()
        .groupby(level=0)
        .value_counts()
        .unstack(fill_value=0))
print (df1)
   t1  t2  t3
0   3   1   2
1   1   2   0
```

Or:

```
from collections import Counter

df1 = (pd.DataFrame([Counter(x) for i, x in df['Hey'].iteritems()], index=df.index)
        .fillna(0).astype(int))
print (df1)
   t1  t2  t3
0   3   1   2
1   1   2   0
```

Comment: Beautiful. Which one would you recommend ?

Comment: @EranMoshe - It depends of amount of data, I guess first and last should be very fast.

Comment: @jezrael I think there's a problem in the Counter solution: what if a key is only present at one row?

Comment: @游凯超 - Do you think there are not lists ?

Comment: @游凯超 Your question is whether there's a problem is missing keys, example "t3" in one list but not the other, right? That is fixed by the fillna call... you have NaNs generated from concat aligned on the index which you fill with 0s... of course jezrael could have told you that since he came up with this answer all on his own... but I explained anyway to save him the trouble.

Comment: @EranMoshe I tried and it works. As  mentioned by coldspeed, it is solved by ``fillna``

Comment: I'm going to work with the first solution anyway, with the sklearn package supported. Thanks Jezrael!

Answer (score 1):

Concise `Counter` based alternative:

```
from collections import Counter
df = (pd.DataFrame([Counter(x) for i, x in df['Hey'].items()], index=df.index)
        .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))
df
   t1  t2  t3
0   3   1   2
1   1   2   0
```

Comment: Sorry coldspeed, Eventhough the fillna I'm still getting an error with this solution: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 2), indices imply (3, 3). I'm going to use the CountVectorizer(). Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding about [sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html). 
Since it is called Binarizer, it count whether a key occurs. That is to say, the value is binarized : if a key occurs, it is 1, otherwise it is 0. It doesn't count occurances.